# mT5 Question/Answering fine tuning is generating empty sentences during inference

Tags: deep-learning, nlp-question-answering, fine-tuning, large-language-model

mT5-small Question Answering training is converging to high accuracy, high validation accuracy, near-zero low loss; however, when testing the model on trained questions, I am always receiving empty answers.

- Experiment Language: Arabic
- Dataset used: Arabic SQUAD
- Optimizer tested: Adam or AdamW with learning rate: 3e-4
- loss function: tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
- Epochs tested: 5, 30

I tried to train the model with 30 epochs and the same result is obtained:

> Output:   <extra_id_0>
> Output:  [0, 250099, 1]

It is very strange that the model is converging to high accuracy and low loss and I am getting empty sentences during inference. I validated the dataset questions and answers and they are correct.

Below are some important code snippets:

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
    padding = "max_length"
    max_length = 200
    inputs = [ex for ex in examples["question"]]
    targets = [ex for ex in examples["text"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, max_length=max_length, padding=padding, truncation=True)
    labels = tokenizer(targets, max_length=max_length, padding=padding, truncation=True)
    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs

data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(
            tokenizer,
            model=model,
            label_pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,
            pad_to_multiple_of=64,
            return_tensors="np",
        )

tf_train_dataset = model.prepare_tf_dataset(
            train_dataset,
            collate_fn=data_collator,
            batch_size=8,
            shuffle=True,
        )

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5) 
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(3e-5), loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

- Output:

> below are the output of model.fit() for the first 5 epochs
>
> accuracy  ▁████
>
> epoch ▁▃▅▆█
>
> loss  █▁▁▁▁
>
> val_accuracy  ▁▆███
>
> val_loss  █▂▁▁▁

- Run summary:

> accuracy  0.96812
> best_epoch    4
> best_val_loss 0.21643
> epoch 4
> loss  0.35643
> val_accuracy  0.97813
> val_loss  0.21643

- Sample question:

> Q:  ['ما هي قيمة العقد بين شركة Under Armor و Notre Dame؟']
>
> A:  قيمته 100 مليون دولار
>
> A:  [259, 42501, 3234, 966, 548, 36270, 259, 36136, 1]
>
> Input:  ما هي قيمة العقد بين شركة Under Armor و Notre Dame؟
>
> Input:  [1415, 7383, 2588, 23283, 402, 27419, 5373, 259, 11319, 8427,
> 259, 117220, 341, 259, 37126, 34600, 2273, 1]
>
> Output:   <extra_id_0>
>
> Output:  [0, 250099, 1]